# Normalization is better or Creating Indexes without Normalisation

Tags: mysql, database

I'm confused in modelling the database my requirement is

Below two schema's I thought to implement

## 1 First

```
colleges(id,name)
col_course_relation(colleges.id,courses.id)
courses(id,stream,degree,coursename)
```

Example for courses may be

```
(1,"Engineering","Bachelor of Engineering","Computer Science & Engineering")
(2,"Engineering","Master of Engineering","Computer Science & Engineering")
(3,"Engineering","Bachelor of Technology,"Computer Science & Engineering")
(4,"Engineering","Master of Technology","Computer Science & Engineering")
```

Is it better to use normal form for courses table or I can create a index for all the columns,

If i do normalisation the the schema become

## 2 Second

```
colleges(id,name)
col_course_relation(colleges.id,courses.id)
stream(id,streamname)
degree(id,degreename,stream.id)
courses(id,coursename,degree.id)
```

or #3 Third

```
colleges(id,name)
col_course_relation(colleges.id,courses.id,stream.id,degree.id)
stream(id,streamname)
degree(id,degreename)
courses(id,coursename)
```

But whenever mapping this things in UI, stream automatically selected on the basis of degree.

In perspective of performance and ease to write queries which schema is better. there will be around 50k colleges * 10 courses so the reason i'm thinking & asking the question.

Comment: The question on the right structure for the data depends on how the data is going to be used.  There are cases, no doubt, where any of the three might be best, depending on the purpose of the database.

Comment: It *looks* like you think *normalization* means "replace text with id numbers". That's not what it means. There's no such thing as "every-table-has-an-id-number normal form".

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I've not even worked with the medium databases, Now how can i know future challenges, I'm asking suggestion. so to reduce challenges after implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Please normalize.

- it would be better for whoever looks at the schema later on
- it would save space as you will not have unnecessary duplication of values for all records
- it does offer performance benefits
- *and other advantages* 
  e.g. http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/databases216.htm

Comment: ok, but using relationship table is better or one column in relating table like **foreign key college.university_id references university.id **

Comment: You will need a relationship table because of the 'many-to-many' relationship between courses and colleges, either way. Creating foreign keys helps and makes your DB more robust - recommended.